# Namespaces C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

I would like to use (usign NamePrject.Queries;) but when i compile show me an error.

using MvcApplication2.Queries;

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Queries' does not exist in the namespace 'MvcApplication2' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\marsimon\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Controllers\NuevoController.cs  7   23  MvcApplication2

if you could help thanks

Comment: Where are you declaring any types in the `MvcApplication2.Queries` namespace? Is it in a different assembly?

Comment: I don't understand. What is `NamePrject`, what is `MvcApplication2`? I take it the former is the name of the project, the latter - of the solution. Do you use `using NameProject.Queries` or `MvcApplication2.Queries`, which one is it? Where is this `Queries` namespace located? Is it a project in its own right, or not?

Comment: Where did you come up with `NameProject.Queries`? Are you following some example? Can you show us a link or something so we can understand more?

Comment: So you have a class within the project that's inside the mentioned namespace? Can you show us that class?

Answer (score 1):

`using NamespaceName` just brings the names from the namespace into the scope. But what assembly are those names(within the namespace in question) located in? If it is the same assembly you're currently using, then you've mistyped the assembly name. If it is another assembly, you should [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to that assembly! (take the hint of the compiler)

Comment: A namespace is not (always) linked to an assembly. That's just a default convention of VS.

Comment: @Henk. I know, I just wanted it to be clear to the OP... Edited

Comment: It could be just as well (or even more likely) just be in another folder in the main (only) Project.